# Grab the events from the Hardware buttons [Android Auto]

Tags: android, android-auto

Can't seem to grab the events from the Hardware buttons.

Setting the Media session callback and doing this:

```
mSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
```

But no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing the setActive on the MediaSession.